# How do I join fields of a form with codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have this snippet of code

```
<input type="text" id="name1" name="name1">
<input type="text" id="name2" name="name2">
<input type="text" id="name3" name="name3">
```

And I want to concat them inside a variable (something like $variable = name1.name2.name3), so I could set that value inside an array (in the controller) like this:

```
$form_data = array(

    'Name' => set_value($variable),
    'Sexo' => $this->input->post('optionsRadios')   
    );
```

I don't know if the above code is possible, but that's the idea for this thing that I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
$variable = $this->input->post('name1')
          . $this->input->post('name2')
          . $this->input->post('name3');
```

Comment: but what about the spaces between one name and another?, it does this RICHARDSTALLMAN

Comment: The just do `$this->input->post('name1').' '.$this->input->post...`

Comment: Suggestion: Why not add a link to [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in your answer.